# Using Joomla 1.5 based site, I am experiencing a problem while making JAPopup plugin work with Template 29042 from template-help.com

Tags: plugins, youtube, joomla1.5

JAPopup is a handy plugin for Joomla to render Youtube videos in a Modal Window so user cannot click on multiple Youtube videos at the same time. The website URL is www.multicorewareinc.com/29042 (hast not gone live yet!). If I use a standard Joomla template such as JA_Parity or rhuk_mllkyway, JAPopup plugin works fine. But instead if I use Template 29042 from template-help.com, JAPopup hangs up. I compared the index.php files of a working template (such as rhuk_milkyway) and Template 29042 and as far as I can tell, 29042 uses Javascript extensively and there appears to be an issue when it comes to launching JAPopup (which too is based on Javascript). I put print statements in all the JAPopup modules and verified that the code was getting executed in either templates. So I am at a loss as to why JAPopup won't execute. If anyone has a suggestion, I would be grateful. Once I fix this, I plan on publishing the problem and the fix on my web-site, www.sreeiyer.com.

Answer (score 0):

What does Firebug say? It's obviously a jscript conflict so start narrowing down the options - does the template use jQuery or another library? Does JAPopup use a library? You can also remove the scripting from the template and start adding it back until the error comes back, then you know what needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Thank you... The changes were in several places in the template PHP file but after fixing this issue, some new bugs have cropped up! Still looking into it...